# SQL Buffer pages rapidly increasing SQL Server memory usage

Tags: c#, sql-server, memory, buffer

I have written a program to extract PDF files stored in a database, and store them to the file system. This will be executed against tables containing around 2 million records. The program grabs the data in chunks of 1000 documents per query (which are executed in parallel using a small c# application).

The problem which I am facing is the memory usage of SQL Server. I eventually get a `System.OutOfMemory` exception and need to terminate the program (I don't have the exception details anymore), and the allocated memory appears to be used by the amount of buffer pages. After running the program for 5 minutes, I have executed 194'443 pages, taking 1519MB of memory.

I have tried using `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and this works, however this is not an option as I will be running this program on customers sites, and do not want to affect any other database.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent SQL Server from storing the pages in memory, or to flush this particular portion of memory used without affecting any other database within that instance?

I am connecting to the database using a C# application. My data provider works using PetaPoco, and it uses `System.Data.SqlClient` classes to connect to a SQL Server database.

Comment: post the code. in your description there is no information that can be used to help you. how you connect to the db? are you using the `USING` statement? are there pending connections? have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints about how to ask.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured max memory properly? Are you running other applications on the same server? SQL Server shouldn't just run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

You can't selectively flush portions of memory in SQL Server. Instead of 1000 documents per query, start with something smaller, perhaps 100, then test your way up to a "reasonable" state. A single READ that results in retrieving 1000 docs means SQL Server has to cache all of that to service your query and cannot release any of it until your query has completed. That's potentially a really long time depending on what else you have in that transaction, IO capacity, etc...

Apart from the memory, you're potentially blocking other queries while you're working through the 1000 docs which will likely make your customers equally unhappy with random DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS